# TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str - JSON, Python error

Tags: json, python-3.x, api

```
    {
        "gameId": 32,
        "participantIdentities": [
            {
                "player": {
                    "id": "123",
                    "name": "xxx",
                },
                "participantId": 1
            },
            {
                "player": {
                    "id": "123",
                    "name": "yyyy",   
                },
                "participantId": 2
            }
        ]

        "gameDuration": 143,
    }
```

I am trying to print names in this json file in python 3

```
    list_id = []
    for info in matchinfo['participantIdentities']['player']['name']:
        list_id.append(info)
```

But I get the following error below

```
    TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

How do I get the content of 'name'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues:

1. You provided an invalid JSON. `matchinfo['participantIdentities']` should be a list but the JSON you provided is missing a closing `]`
2. `matchinfo['participantIdentities']` is a list, so you should either provide an index (`matchinfo['participantIdentities'][0]['player']['summonerId']` for example) or iterate over all `matchinfo['participantIdentities']` entries.
3. You are trying to access a key that doesn't even exist (at least in the JSON you provided). There is no `'summonerId'` key anywhere.

Comment: 1. It is still invalid (try to call `json.loads` on it). 2. The key you are trying to access still doesn't exist. 3. Point 2 in my answer still answers your question.